# Bootstrap tagsinput - stop the input box from dynamically changing size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have an email form and have incorporated bootstrap's tagsinput feature thanks to a great codepen I found:

My external references are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
```

And then I have the following HTML form my email input:

```
<div class="formGroupContainer green">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="toAddress"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> To: Email address</label>
        <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" multiple="multiple" name="toAddress" class="form-control" id="tags" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value=<?=toEmail?>>
</div>
```

It's working beautifully. However, one thing I really want to override is the fact that when you start typing in the text area, the input box dynamically suddenly changes width depending on the number of characters typed. When you delete email addresses out, the box becomes tiny and obviously this all looks a bit messy.

I inspected the element in the browser's dev tools and noticed an attribute that says placeholder size="1"... when I change this in the dev tools to 40, for example, I get the full width again.

So my question is how I can stop this from happening. I just want the input to be a set width of 250px and not to change depending on what is inside. I tried:

```
    #toAddress {
       min-width: 250px !important;
       size: 40;
    }
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply your width to the wrong element. In addition, if you do not want width to change you should just apply the width property and not min-width.

Should be:

```
#tags{
       width: 250px !important;
       size: 40;
    }
```

Comment: thanks. Sadly not working though. The input box still changes width dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row and col div class feature to structure the form.

so for your code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-1">
   <label for="toAddress"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  To: Email address</label>
    <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" multiple="multiple" name="toAddress" class="form-control" id="tags" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value=<?=toEmail?>>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers. Unfortunately though this is not working. Presumably there is something in one of the JS files I am referencing that is causing this behaviour?? Just can't seem to pinpoint it...

Answer (score 0):

Aha I solved it :)

Was simple! I simply needed to apply my CSS as follows:

```
input {
  width: 250px !important;
}
```

Cheers guys